# Transferring android project which uses SHA-1 key, to another pc

Tags: android, sha1

I want to move my android project from the android studio on my pc to android studio on another pc but my project uses google login, facebook login, and google maps, all of which use my SHA-1 key. 
I would manually change SHA-1 key on the other pc but I do not have access to it.
Is there ANY way to move a project to another pc without changing the SHA-1 key or is there any easier alternative than manually locating and changing everywhere I have used the SHA-1.

Any advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, copy the debug key from your old setup to your new setup and rebuild with it. That file is in ~/.android/debug.keystore.
In that case your SHA1 key will not change.

To get SHA1 key in your new setup (this should return same sha1 key),

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Hope it will be help.